# most efficient ruby way to transform this array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, loops, iteration

I have  an array in the following form:

```
  [\"id\", 545, \"program_name\", \"VILLIANS MARATHON\", \"episode_name\", \"1-Season1:Ep.11\"]
```

I need to transform it to the form  below:

```
  [545, \"VILLIANS MARATHON\", \"1-Season1:Ep.11\"]
```

The way Im doing this is as follows:

```
    #Convert a Active record hash to a 2D array
def activerecord_hash_to_datatable_array(activerecord_resultset)
array_of_arrays = Array.new()
array_of_rs_hashes = activerecord_resultset.to_a.map(&:serializable_hash)

array_of_rs_hashes.each do |rs| 
# {"id"=>1594, "program_name"=>nil, "episode_name"=>nil}
rs =  rs.flatten
#[\"id\", 545, \"program_name\", \"MARATHON\", \"episode_name\", \"1-Season1:Ep.11\"]"
rs_array = Array.new()
index = 1
while index < rs.length     
    puts "index = #{index}"     
    puts "\033[0;33m"+"#{rs[index]}"+"\033[0;37m"
    log_with_yellow("index[#{index}] " + "#{rs[index]}")
    rs_array << rs[index]
    index += 2
end
array_of_arrays <<  rs_array
end
array_of_arrays
end
```

I was wondering what the most efficient way to accomplish this is.

Clearly I need to retain only odd elements. But Id like to avoid iterating over all elements and comparing each elements index.

Is there a way to do this by skipping all the even elements ?

Thanks

Comment: this is no 2D array but a single array, looks like a JSON object stored in an array

Comment: @bjhaid - he has an array of such arrays.

Comment: @BroiSatse its a JSON object, check my answer and you would understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
your_array.values_at(*your_array.each_index.select(&:odd?))
=> [545, "VILLIANS MARATHON", "1-Season1:Ep.11"]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'json'
arr = JSON.parse("[\"id\", 545, \"program_name\", \"VILLIANS MARATHON\", \"episode_name\", \"1-Season1:Ep.11\"]")
new_arr = arr.select.with_index { |x,i| i.odd? }
p new_arr
# >> [545, "VILLIANS MARATHON", "1-Season1:Ep.11"]
```

Comment: I think this is the correct way to do it. Since it's a json, your given array isn't really an array due to the '\'s. So you would need to JSONify them to make a valid array, on which you can then perform select.

Answer (score 1):

If `array_of_rs_hashes` is indeed an array of hashes, can't you just do:

```
res = array_of_rs_hashes.map(&:values)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yep there is :

```
require 'json'
Hash[*JSON.parse(s)].values #=> [545, "VILLIANS MARATHON", "1-Season1:Ep.11"]
```

where `s = "[\"id\", 545, \"program_name\", \"VILLIANS MARATHON\", \"episode_name\", \"1-Season1:Ep.11\"]"`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
your_2d_array.map {|a| a.each_slice(2).map {|key, value| value}}
```

If you ahve active support, you can write it slightly more readible:

```
your_2d_array.map {|a| a.each_slice(2).map(&:second)}
```

Comment: But I dont want to put magic numbers in my code. Id like the code to be extendible. This wont work if used on arrays where length is bigger than 6 !